# pyqt sizehint method is not working without classlevel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

if i use QtGui.QWidget in classlevel it gives me the window size by self.sizeHint() method

```
class MainWin(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        print(self.sizeHint())
```

but if i use  QtGui.QWidget without class just mentioned below.it just printing 
PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(-1, -1). what is the problem?

```
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QtGui.QWidget()
print(win.sizeHint())
win.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
win.show()


app.exec_()
```

Comment: Would the sizeHine still return -1/-1 when called after show()?

Comment: still shows PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(-1, -1)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. First code sample also gives me (-1, -1). May be your real code has significant difference. And size hint is (-1, -1) by default, this is correct behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of `sizeHint()` returns an invalid size (-1,-1) if there is no layout for widget, and returns the layout's preferred size otherwise.
So, you need to set some layout (works for both cases):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWin(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        lay = QtGui.QGridLayout() 
        self.setLayout(lay)
        print "case 1: ", self.sizeHint()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    #case 1   
    win=MainWin()
    win.show()

    #case 2
    win1 = QtGui.QWidget()
    win1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)   
    lay = QtGui.QGridLayout() 
    win1.setLayout(lay)    
    win1.show()
    print "case 2: ", win1.sizeHint()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```